# product view count table in database magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, product-view, table, count

I have to write code for getting product count.it is working fine but i want to know where the count record comes?

```
public function getProductCount($id)
{

    $prodData = $this->_prodCollection->addViewsCount()->getData();

    if (count($prodData) > 0) {
        foreach ($prodData as $product) {
            if ($product['entity_id'] == $id) {
                return (int) $product['views'];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$productData` is an array and the `count` definition is from here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: what about the table name?from where it get count?

Answer (score 0):

After wasting half of the day finally i find the table name i.e report_event.Basically whenever a page is requested a row is added in this table and when we call method addviewscount() it return array of products which are in report_event table and then we apply filter on entity_id it will return the product count .